# Google Play does not download application when VPN connection is active

Tags: google-play-store, vpn, openvpn

I use OpenVPN Connect. When VPN connection is active Google Play can show pages, pictures, video, but does not download the application: "pending...".
To begin download I need to disable VPN, then it works. Tell me how to research a problem and make GPlay work over VPN?

Comment: If all other apps work fine, then VPN client app or the VPN server must be blocking the connections to Google servers.

Comment: I have tried different servers and different VPN provides including VPS hostings. Almost all of them cannot download APKs. I am pretty sure Google intentionally is protecting APKs from being downloaded through VPN.

Answer (score -1, accepted):

After all, I found [Aurora Store](https://f-droid.org/en/packages/com.aurora.store/). It is like Google's Play Store, but has some cool features like anonymous apk download, sharing, version selection, etc.

Answer (score 0):

"Since VPNs basically spoof your location, it may lead Google Play Store to think you aren’t in the country where you should be according to your device, and it can pause your downloads.

If that’s the case, there really isn’t much you need to do to fix the issue. All you need to do is disable the VPN app on your phone and you should be good to go." [Source](https://helpdeskgeek.com/help-desk/how-to-resolve-the-play-store-download-pending-issue/)

It is my experience that google play store DOES block your downloads if you are using VPN. (in my case openvpn)

What you can do:

1. disconnect your VPN (you do not need to disable your app, only disconnect while you are downloading)
2. turn off mobile data (even if you are connected currently via WIFI, this can help too)

Comment: Sure, Gigle used to block downloading APKs through VPN. I do not want to disable VPN! That is not even considered as any usable solution. I appreciate your port but it is not an answer. I definitely know that it works without vpn as you can see in my question. Suggesting to disable vpn sounds strange - this is obvious anti-solution. ;(

Comment: You have to disable only while downloading, after that you can enable it. In openVPN it is only one click to switch off, after that you can click one more and the VPN will be active again.
Personally i would not trust any 3rd party site to install my APKs, what is the point to use VPN if you let the trojan horse into your house?

Comment: I know. I used to do so. But once you disable VPN and "kill switch" your location, family (who goes to internet from same IP), and too much other information are gathered in a moment by gigle. Disabling VPN is not a solution.